# JSScripts not working in AngularJS ui-view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, uiview

I have an **angularJS** based web application which generated by **Jhipster**. While integrating the theme in this application, an issue occurs like all component of this theme works fine in **Index.html** but in there nested UI-view some scripts do not work properly like dropdowns, carousels.

If I pasted my whole code in Index.html file. It works totally fine not in there ui-view.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css content/css/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css content/css/main.css -->
  
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/hs-megamenu/src/hs.megamenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/custombox/dist/custombox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/dzsparallaxer/dzsparallaxer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/vendor/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css">

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; CSS Space Template &ndash;&gt;-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/space/css/theme.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webapp" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>

<div ui-view="content"></div>

 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/messageformat/messageformat.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/stomp-websocket/lib/stomp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/clipboard/dist/clipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-rating/bootstrap-rating.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-mockjax/dist/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/install/detect-zoom.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/autosize/dist/autosize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cache-buster/angular-cache-buster.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker/dist/datetime-picker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngclipboard/dist/ngclipboard.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js app/app.js  -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/hs-megamenu/src/hs.megamenu.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/custombox/dist/custombox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/custombox/dist/custombox.legacy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/custombox/dist/custombox.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/dzsparallaxer/dzsprx_module_parallax_features.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/dzsparallaxer/dzsparallaxer.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/dzsparallaxer/dzsparallaxer.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/cubeportfolio/documentation/js/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/cubeportfolio/documentation/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/player.js/dist/player.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/vendor/appear.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/theme-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/hs.core.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/helpers/hs.focus-state.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/helpers/hs.bg-video.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.video-player.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.validation.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.unfold.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.sticky-block.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.step-form.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.slick-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.show-animation.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.scroll-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.quantity-counter.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.progress-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.onscroll-animation.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.modal-window.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.malihu-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.instagram.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.header.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.go-to.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.g-map.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.cubeportfolio.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.counter.js"></script>
    <script src="app/space/js/components/hs.countdown.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
`bower.json
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "my-app",
  "appPath": "src/main/webapp/",
  "testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.8",
     "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
     "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
     "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
     "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.32",
     "angular-i18n": "1.5.8",
     "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
     "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
     "angular-resource": "1.5.8",
     "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
     "angular-translate": "2.11.1",
     "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.11.1",
     "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.11.1",
     "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.11.1",
     "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
     "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.4.3",
     "json3": "3.3.2",
     "messageformat": "0.3.1",
     "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
     "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.3.0",
     "sockjs-client": "1.1.1",
     "stomp-websocket": "2.3.4",
     "swagger-ui": "2.1.5",
     "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
     "ngclipboard": "^2.0.0",
     "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
     "jquery": "^3.3.1",
     "font-awesome": "4",
     "modernizr": "^3.5.0",
     "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
     "bootstrap-rating": "^1.5.0",
     "nestable": "*",
     "select2": "^4.0.5",
     "blockUI": "blockui#*",
     "jquery-mockjax": "^2.2.1",
     "install": "^1.0.4",
     "jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14.13",
     "autosize": "^4.0.0",
     "ckeditor-dev": "^4.8.0",
     "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
     "jQuery-Smart-Wizard": "^3.3.1",
     "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
     "moment": "^2.20.1",
     "gmaps": "^0.4.25",
     "echarts": "^4.0.4"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "angular-mocks": "1.5.8"
   },
   "overrides": {
      "angular": {
        "dependencies": {
          "jquery": "3.3.1"
        }
       },
      "angular-cache-buster": {
        "dependencies": {
          "angular": "1.5.8"
        }
       },
     "angular-dynamic-locale": {
       "dependencies": {
         "angular": "1.5.8"
        }
     }
   },
   "resolutions": {
      "angular": "1.5.8",
      "angular-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
      "jquery": "3.1.0"
    }
 }`
```

Comment: from a general view, this is because your theme is based on jquery, and those code are outside of your main controller, and views. maybe you should move jquery codes inside directives, in order to make them execute

Comment: Ali Bahrami Thank you for Reply, can you please explain it in detail...